# BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{Any,1} at index [2]

Tags: julia, bounds

```
for i in 1:1000
    x = rand(Uniform(0,4),100)
    mean_array[i] = sum(x)/ 100
end
```

I wanna generate 1000 dists and calculate the mean of each one and put the means in an array to get another mean from this 1000 means.

Comment: but unfortunately I see this error:BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{Any,1} at index [2]

Comment: Ali, please provide a reproducible example so I can try running the code.

Comment: solved.....   x = zeros(0)
for i in 1:1000
append!( x, sum(rand(Uniform(0,4),100))/100 )
end

Comment: Great, please put the solution as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be written as:

```
mean_array=[mean(rand(Uniform(0,4),100)) for i in 1:100]
```